# Website in Flash/HTML5. on iPad?

Tags: flash, html, web, unity-game-engine

A customer of mine wants a total new website. He wants to use the newest possibilities. The website he want has to be made in either HTML5 or in Flash. Thing however is that the website must work on the iPad.

I told him that his idea is not very smart and practical to do. We all know some browsers lack the support of HTML5 (He said he does not care, they will have to use an other browser). Plus there's the issue with Flash and the iPad. I don't really think it's smart to make the visitors install an app or different browser just so they can see his website.

So my question really is what the possibilities are. Can HTML5 be used on the iPad for a website (not an app!) without installing anything? Or is it necessary to install other software to use HTML5 and Flash.

I also wonder if it's possible to use something like Unity. Although I do not really believe it is possible to make a website with it.

Demands:

- Website in either Flash or HTML5
- Website must work on the iPad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use HTML in order to support the iPad, but there is no need for desktop users to install a new browser. Properly written HTML5/CSS3 should degrade gracefully for older browsers that lack support.  To make this task easier you should look at existing templates like [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which handle the cross browser issues for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use a third party framework like mordernizr http://www.modernizr.com. The advantage with this is that , you would write one code, and the framework will take care of creating the html/javascript/css for you.

With this you reduce the risk of changing your code at a later point of time, as the framework will take care of using the right kind of DOM elements where and whenever they are supported in the browser.

Also, flash with iPad is not possible as pointed out by a shanethehat and Ian.

Answer (score 1):

Flash doesn't work on the iPad, a design decision by Apple, so if the site must work on the iPad, it rules Flash out immediately.

So use HTML5.